# Why does my Django app attempt to create migrations, when it is defined to not allow migrations in a router?

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I've got a Django app called `dataapi` which is built by introspecting a PostgreSQL database to write various models files (one for each schema). It works and provides us read-only access to the data we need via the ORM, but I break up models into multiple files by schema rather than putting them all in a (huge) models.py file.

I've defined a `ROOT/config/routers.py` file tell Django I don't want this app's models to use migrations:

```
class DataAPIRouter(object):
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in the
    dataapi application.
    """

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to read dataapi models go to mssqlwrds.
        """

        if model._meta.app_label == 'dataapi':
            return 'pgdata'
        return None


    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to write dataapi models go to mssqlwrds.
        """

        if model._meta.app_label == 'dataapi':
            return 'pgdata'
        return None


    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Allow relations if a model in the dataapi app is involved.
        """

        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'dataapi' or obj2._meta.app_label == 'dataapi':
            return True
        return None


    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """
        Make sure the dataapi app doesn't use migrations.
        """

        if app_label == 'dataapi':
            return False
        return True
```

In my settings, I've defined the router:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = [
    'config.routers.DataAPIRouter',
]
```

Yet when I run a dry run using `makemigrations`, it still shows that it's hitting the app:

```
(project) [vagrant@vagrant project]$ ./manage.py makemigrations --dry-run
Migrations for 'dataapi':
  0001_initial.py:
    - Create model aco_amda
    - Create model aco_imda
    - Create model aco_indfnta
    - Create model aco_indfntq
    [...]
```

Am I missing something? How can I get this app to be ignored by migrations?

Comment: It is ignored. `allow_migrate` prevents the _execution_ of migrations in the `dataapi` app. It still creates the migrations, that's just how it works.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarifications. I'll issue a PR to update the documentation with this clarification. Much appreciated! If you submit this as an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, this is by design. As @knbk pointed out, this setting in the router only stops the migration from happening when you execute `python manage.py migrate`. It will still *create* the migrations when you run `python manage.py makemigrations`. I have issued a PR to Django to clarify this in the documentation which has been accepted.

Comment: Hey. I just ran into this. So am I supposed to delete the generated migration? If I don't delete it, the app shows up in the list of migrations during a `migrate` command, e.g. `Operations to perform:  Apply all migrations: app_that_shouldnt_show_up, auth, contenttypes, sessions. Running migrations:  Applying app_that_shouldnt_show_up.0001_initial... OK ...`

Comment: It has been a while since I worked on this, but I believe I just faked it with `python manage.py migrate appname --fake`. That'll mark it as run in the database without actually running it, IIRC.